# Maximum bipartite matching

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Currently best known algorithm for maximum bipartite matching is O(√VE).

Here is what my algorithm is to solve the above problem:
Given two sets S1 and S2 and E edges between them.

step1: sort both S1 and S2 in increasing order on the basis of their degree

step 2: pick the element of the set in sorted order and assign it to the next free element of the other set count the number of matching.

step 3: perform the step 2 on S1 and then on S2.

step 4: take maximum of step 3.

which makes the complexity above algorithm O(Vlog(V)+(V+E)).

I can't prove the correctness of above algorithm so can any one help me with any counter example on which the above example fail, as this algo not works on spoj problem [MATCHING](https://www.spoj.com/problems/MATCHING/) so algorithm is wrong but can't figure out the counter example.

Thanks

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;


int main(){

    ll c,b,p;
    cin >> c >> b >> p;
    c+=1;
    b+=1;
    ll mx = max(c,b);
    c =mx;
    b =mx;
    vector<ll> adjcow[c];
    vector<ll> adjbull[b];

    for(ll i=0; i<p; i++){
        ll x,y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        adjcow[x].push_back(y);
        adjbull[y].push_back(x);
    }

    /*
    for(ll i=0; i<c; i++){
        cout << i << " ";
        for(auto x:adjcow[i])
            cout << x << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    for(ll i=0; i<b; i++){
        cout << i << " ";
        for(auto x : adjbull[i])
            cout << x << " ";
        cout << endl; 
    }
    */

    vector<pair<ll, ll>> deg1(c);
    vector<pair<ll, ll>> deg2(b);


    for(ll i=0; i<c; i++){
        ll count = 0;
        for(auto x: adjcow[i])
            count++;
        deg1[i] = {count, i};
    }

    for(ll i=0; i<b; i++){
        ll count = 0;
        for(auto x: adjbull[i])
            count++;
        deg2[i] = {count,i};
    }

    sort(deg1.begin(), deg1.end());
    sort(deg2.begin(), deg2.end());

    vector<bool> isTaken1(c,0);
    vector<bool> isTaken2(b,0);

    /*
    for(ll i=0; i<c; i++)
        cout << deg1[i].first << " " << deg1[i].second  << ", ";

    cout << endl;

    for(ll i=0; i<b; i++) 
        cout << deg2[i].first <<" "<< deg2[i].second  << ", ";

    cout << endl;
    */

    ll ansCow =0;
    for(auto x:deg1){
        ll node = x.second;
        for(auto u: adjcow[node]){
            if(isTaken1[u]==0){
    //          cout << node << "-> " << u << "\n";
                isTaken1[u] = 1;
                ansCow++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //cout << "\n\n";

    ll ansBull =0;
    for(auto x:deg2){
        ll node = x.second;
        for(auto u: adjbull[node]){
            if(isTaken2[u]==0){
    //          cout << node << "->" << u << "\n";
                isTaken2[u] = 1;
                ansBull++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << max(ansCow, ansBull) << "\n";
}
```

Input::

```
5 4 6
5 2
1 2
4 3
3 1
2 2
4 4
```

Comment: I think it's better to provide your code here

Comment: code is added(c++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counter-example is shown below. Note that every node has degree 2, so sorting has no effect. When connecting from left to right, if 1 chooses A, and 2 chooses B, then 3 cannot be connected. So the result is 2. When connecting from right to left, if A chooses 1 and B chooses 2, then C cannot be connected. The result is 2 again. But the correct result is 3, with 1 connected to C, 2 connected to B, and 3 connected to A.

[image]

The input to the program would be:

```
3 3 6
1 1
1 3
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
```